# Header-Files missing in boost build

Tags: c++, boost

I cloned the current boost sources from the github repository: https://github.com/boostorg/boost including all referenced child repository.

I did boostrap and build the sources on a OS X machine with the latest XCode command line tools. The build seems to work fine.

But in the `$BOOST_ROOT/boost/` directory, where the header files are linked from the library directories (e.g. `/boost/graph/adjacency_iterator.hpp -> ../../libs/graph/include/boost/graph/adjacency_iterator.hpp`), some of the header files are missing. For example there is an `boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp` in `./libs/graph/include/boost/graph` which is missing in the build output. The same happens if I call the `install` target. The header files are missing in the destination.

What do I have to do, that all header files get included in the build.
Regards

Joachim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation ([Installing Modular Boost](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/wiki/Getting-Started)) you should

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 headers
```

to link the headers to the include directory when using Modular Boost

Comment: This should be inside boostrap.sh/bootstrap.bat

Comment: @schoetbi note that things are a little different for modular boost, which this question is about. Yes initial bootstrap should work, but when one sub module is changed/updated (e.g. switched to another branch) the `b2 headers` command should update the headers. I think the headers are sym-linked on platforms that support it, to avoid having to rebuild the headers every time.