# boost/filesystem.hpp not in install directory

Tags: boost

I've been working on a source build of boost, which I've installed via the following commands:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/some_dir/boost_install
./b2 install link=shared threading=multi variant=release --without-mpi --without-coroutine --without-context
```

I then tried to compile some client code which `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`. This brokee, which is unsurprising. More surprising is that `find` comes up dry in the install directory:

```
find /some_dir/boost_install -name "filesystem.hpp"
```

but not in the cloned directory:

```
find boost -name "filesystem.hpp"
boost/libs/filesystem/include/boost/filesystem.hpp
```

Why didn't boost filesystem get included in the install? Note that other files are put in the install directory, like `boost/filesystem/path.hpp`.

Comment: No, that typo popped up in the post. But just in case I reran it to make sure.

Comment: I'm far from sure, but could it be the same problem shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158084/header-files-missing-in-boost-build).

Comment: That was it. Want to add this as an answer?

Comment: You should upvote sehe's answer there, and I'm sure this question will be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: It is a duplicate indeed. You must execute
./b2 ... headers
in order to link the headers
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158084/header-files-missing-in-boost-build?noredirect=1&lq=1